# Wordpress PHP Errors tag wrap and css style?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, error-handling, compiler-errors

Sometimes I am using code below to normalise look of my Wordpress websites - remove some white space around divs and give 0 width and height to `:before` and `:after` elements

```
*{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

It works great, but when I am testing for errors with `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` the errors don't appear, until I disable the css style, or inspect the website.

My question - **is it possible to wrap the errors in `<p>` tags or something similar?**

Currently errors are just displayed like below

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_get_content() in /Users/maksym/htdocs/my-wp-website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/index.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/maksym/htdocs/my-wp-website/wp-includes/template-loader.php(77): include()
#1 /Users/maksym/htdocs/my-wp-website/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/Users/maksym/h...')
#2 /Users/maksym/htdocs/my-wp-website/index.php(17): require('/Users/maksym/h...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in <b>/Users/maksym/htdocs/my-wp-website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/index.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
```

Already tried googling, but couldn't find anything

**EDIT**

I have managed to get it to work, I had the prepend and append in reverse order, so it would start with `</p>` error `<p>`

Working code below

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_prepend_string', '<p>');
ini_set('error_append_string', '</p>');
```

It also works in the php.ini globally which is what I wanted.

Thank you 04FS and Lajos Arpad,

hope somebody will find it helpful

Comment: Guess you could try and use `error_prepend_string` / `error_append_string` PHP config options …

Comment: Hi 04FS, I have tried that, but it doesn't work? See my answer to Lajos please

Comment: Never mind, got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 04FS pointed out, you can set error_prepent_string and error_append_string values. If you want to do it for a specific page, then:

```
ini_set('error_prepend_string', '<p>');
ini_set('error_append_string', '</p>');
```

If you want this to be a general settings, then you can do something like this in your php.ini:

```
; String to output before an error message. PHP's default behavior is to leave
; this setting blank.
; http://php.net/error-prepend-string
; Example:
;error_prepend_string = "<p>"

; String to output after an error message. PHP's default behavior is to leave
; this setting blank.
; http://php.net/error-append-string
; Example:
;error_append_string = "</p>"
```

However, I think that not showing errors when you are not testing is a feature and has values. It would be great if you would create a dev.css file and load it only when you are testing.

Comment: Hi Lajos, I have tried that in the Wordpress **wp-config.php** and in a **php.ini** without success. My PHP version is 7.1.26, and prepend and append both show up in the `phpinfo()` function [link](https://imgur.com/a/FjppVaN), but the error still looks the same. Could it be it was depreciated in that PHP version? Or is it because I am on local MAMP server? Thanks for help

Comment: @Maksym sorry for the slow reply. I was happy to help. If this answer pointed into the right direction, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: thanks, accepted the answer, but could you please swap error_append_string and error_prepend_string, so it prepends opening `<p>` and appends closing `</p>`